# Dynamic Directives in Angular

Tags: angular, directive

I have a dynamic table. The columns and their formatting are described in a separate structure. I want to format the content of the cell depending on the value with a directive. The directive to use can be specified with the "formatter".

Type definitions:

```js
export interface Table extends BaseItem {
    columns: Array<TableColumn>;
    data: Array<TableRow>;
}

export interface TableColumn {
    id: string;
    label?: string; // header
    type: ColumnType;
    formatter?: string; // special formatter (e.g. valueAsIcon )
}
```

The data in the table object:

```json
{
  id: "diagnosticlist",
  type: "table",
  columns: [
    {
      id: "id",
      label: "Id",
    },
    {
      id: "status",
      label: "Status",
      formatter: "formatNamur",
    },
    {
      id: "remedy",
      label: "Remedy",
      type: "button",
      formatter: "formatShowRemedy",
    },
  ],
  data: [
    {
      id: 0,
      status: "F",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      status: "C",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      status: "S",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      status: "M",
      remedy: "Hello",
    },
  ]
}
```

The directive should be inserted dynamically in the HTML code. Here  **[{{column.formatter}}]**

```html
<table mat-table matSort TableResponsive [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of table?.columns?? []">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.id}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column.label}}</th>

      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [{{column.formatter}}]="">
        {{row[column.id]}}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

The code of the directive

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formatNamur]'
})
export class NamurDirective {
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') bgColor : string;

  constructor() { 
    this.bgColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

- How can I specify the directive directly in the HTML?
- How can I pass the content of the cell to this directive?

Comment: Generally, in Angular it's use one directive and pass as `@Input` one value. You can not inject "on fly" a directive